# Excel/VBA - Error1004 Doing a Cycle with GoalSeek

Tags: vba, loops, excel

When I run this code I manage to fill the table that I want to, but in the last iteration it breaks on the Range("F" & r)... line and gives the error1004. I don't see why. Indeed running it works... but yields the error at the end.

```
Sub Stuff1()
    Dim r As Integer
    r = 37
    Do
        Range("F" & r).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("D" & r)
        r = r + 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty("E" & r)
End Sub
```

Note: I tried doing a Do While Not and it happens exactly the same.
Edit: Excel 2013 btw

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `IsEmpty` function to reference a `Range` not a string as it is doing at the moment..

```
Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("E" & r))
```

Also, you should change your data type of `r` to `Long`. If you attempt to access row 32768 or beyond you will get an Overflow error using an `Integer`.

Regarding your 1004 error...

The goalseek cell must have a formula that references a cell which you want to manipulate. I suspect this will be the reason for your error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Loop Until Range("E" & r)=""
```